# What event fires when the address bar hides or moves?

Tags: javascript, events, window-resize, address-bar

I am trying to resize a `fixed` position `canvas` when my address bar hides on mobile divices. The `canvas` is meant to cover the entire page and I do this with Javascript by setting the `height` and `width` of the `canvas` to `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `clientHeight` respectively. When the address bar hides no `resize` event is fired and I am left with a gap on my screen. Does any event fire when the address bar hides and if so what is that event?